# Using the LibreOffice Spell Checker

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Just installed the latest version of LibreOffice but when I perform spell checking [via ToolS|Spelling] nothing happens.

I then followed the instructions at:

https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries

and download the dictionary file, although I already I saw it locked in the Extensions Manager. However, I added it, which appeared to remove the padlock icon.

After restarting LibreOffice I went back and tried to perform a BASIC spell check operation, and guess what ... still nothing.

I used to use OpenOffice and had the same problems with that. There is clearly something I don't get about performing spell checking in LibreOffice.

If I perform a spell check then it pops up a dialog stating that the check is complete immediately, when on a 300 page document I know it isn't! I can select a text language and user-defined dictionaries from options, but still nothing.

The whole thing is bonkers.

Answer (score 0):

Your user profile may be in some way corrupt, and resetting your user profile may resolve the problem. See, for example, https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=89050, where spellcheck problems were noted as being resolved in this manner.

Additionally, information specifically concerning the LibreOffice user profile and discussing corruption resolution is available at https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile.